# Why past tense in 'I got this'?

Tags: tenses

I came across the phrase 'I got this' in an episode of 'How I Met Your Mother'. In the episode, Robin kept saying 'I got this' whenever something came up that needs dealing with. I guess it means 'Leave this to me. I can handle it'. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20got%20this) says it's short for 'I got this under control.' I think the omission makes sense.

The thing I don't understand is why past tense is used here. When you use 'I got this', you are referring to something in the present, not in the past. Maybe you can get it under control, but you haven't gotten it under control yet. Why do you use past tense?

Here is an example from Urban Dictionary:

> You're are driving a truck full of your stoner friends. The car in
>   front of you slams on its breaks and all of your wasted friends are
>   screaming that they are going to die.
>
> You scream "I GOT THIS!!!" and then you stop your car just inches away
>   from the car's bumper.

It is very clear that you had screamed 'I got this' before you actually got it under control.

Comment: It comes from *I've got this*; it's an Americanism, and it's generally considered to be bad grammar.

Comment: When you accept an answer to this, please add the comment "gotcha". ;)

Comment: @PeterShor I can't dismiss such a commonly used phrase as simply ungrammatical. =.=

Comment: @JeffSahol Good joke. But that one is actually different. In "gotcha", the beginning of the sentence "I" and "have" is omitted. That's fine. Reserving "I" and omitting only "have" is another thing.

Comment: @Betty: You may not be able to dismiss it as simply ungrammatical, but many other people have no such compunctions. If you use "I got" for "I've got" outside of informal situations, these people will perceive you as having a lower level of sophistication then they do. (Using "I got" as the past tense of "I get" is fine.)

Comment: @PeterShor: was your use of 'then' vs 'than' intentional?

Comment: No, it was a typo.

Comment: @PeterShor - Well, if it is an Americanisim, then in America there would be no such problem, now would there? In fact, I'm inclined to believe you on that point, because I can in fact say that here in America it is perfectly normal to say things like "I got it" or "I got this", no matter what your level of "sophistication".

Comment: @Betty another use of bad grammar that is not going away even in the "smart people" world of computer science and medicine is "I could care less!!" Just heard this a few days ago at the hospital between RNs. After enough people say it, a phrase will become common regardless of correctness.

Comment: The use of "got" in any such usage where the context is present tense, the "got" intends to emphasize the surety/need for urgency. "Surety" as in "Don't worry, I got (confidence that he/she already has a plan to take care of the task, so consider it's already being attended) it" or urgency as in "I got (its so urgent that consider me gone already) to go". I guess that answers the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [OED has this usage back to 1849](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/80217?redirectedFrom=got#eid) so it's been around a while. It says that it comes from omitting *have* and is "colloquial":

> b. **The pa. pple. [past participle] is also used colloq. with omission of (I) have.** Cf. gotcha n., gotta v.
>
> 1849   Knickerbocker 34 12   **They got** no principles. **They got** no platform to stand onto.
>   1857   Quinland I. 1   Got an hour to spare—thought I'd just run in and see what you were all about.
>   1884   ‘M. Twain’ Adventures Huckleberry Finn xxxviii. 325   **We got** to dig in like all git-out.
>   1887   M. E. Wilkins Humble Romance 370   What **you got** there, grandma?
>   1911   R. D. Saunders Col. Todhunter i. 11   Oh, of course, **you got** to laugh at me.
>   1911   J. F. Wilson Land Claimers ix. 118   But **I got** several plans, and I need ye.
>   1941   P. F. Webster & D. Ellington (title of song)    **I got** it bad and that ain't good.
>   1967   L. White Crimshaw Memorandum (1968) v. 93   Gawd knows **I got** enough problems.

---

EDIT: I don't have evidence, so I didn't originally include it in my answer, but my suspicion is that:

In US informal registers, **got** seems to have been re-interpreted as a present-tense verb form just meaning "have, possess". It sure behaves that way. It's homophonous with, but not identical to, the past tense of **get**. Historically it seems to have been a resultative construction, but it acts like a normal verb now.

The only issue is if so, then the verb's defective in the 3sg: both "he/she/it got" and "he/she/it gots" are highly marked and are just avoided in most dialects. In response to Betty's inquiry, I'm not sure sure if people just say "he/she/it's got" or if we reword to avoid the issue.

Again, I got no evidence; it's just a pet theory for now.

Comment: +1: All these references seem to be American. Is this used at all in the U.K.?

Comment: I don't have evidence, so I didn't include it in my answer, but my suspicion is that in US informal registers, **got** has been re-interpreted as a present-tense form just meaning "have, possess". It sure *behaves* that way. It's homophonous with, not identical to, the past tense of "get". Historically it seems to have been a resultative construction, but it acts like a normal verb now. The only issue is the verb's defective in the 3sg: both "he/she/it got" and "he/she/it gots" are highly marked and are just avoided in most dialects. Again, I got no evidence; it's just a pet theory for now :)

Comment: Certainly, children learning to speak in the U.S. often say "he gots", which would tend to confirm that they interpret it that way.

Comment: It was always my impression that there was an implied "have" there, so chalk another one up for the OED. One early reference I might mention comes from Baseball, via Looney Toons. This is from Baseball Bugs, released in 1945: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2dR36mTkyo . I wouldn't be surprised if the source of this idiom wasn't Baseball lingo, and it is shortened from the original "proper" English so it could be yelled in a hurry.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Your comment is more helpful to me than your answer. :) It really seems that "got" has become a present-tense form that happens to be homophonous with the past tense of "get". It makes more sense to me than to say ordinary people have bad grammar. I think you should put it in your answer. Just say it is your speculation. It's OK. :) You say both "he got" and he "gots" should be avoided. I wonder what people would say in the case of third person singular. "He's got"?

Comment: @Betty: If you don't say "he got" (as Mark says, this is marked, but less so than "he gots"), you say "he's got".

Comment: @T.E.D. In sports, clear communication in the shortest time possible is quite important, so "I got it" often takes precedence to "Good sir, I believe that I can handle this situation".  It could be that sports talk has influenced modern speech in this way.

Comment: @T.E.D. That *Baseball Bugs* clip leaves off the punch line from Bugs, "He got it!" (at least on the clip I see). Having played years of baseball in the US in the 70s and 80s, I yelled "I got it!" probably thousands of times. A few hundred I dropped the ball, so clearly it was not in the past tense.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator - Nope, not in this cartoon. This one ends with it on the gravestone. You can see a longer version at http://www.wimp.com/bugsbunny/ . The bit in question is 5 minutes in. I have a vague memory of the one you are talking about perhaps being in a Yosemite Sam cartoon.

Comment: @Zoot, It's not like you have to choose between "I got it" and "Good sir, I believe that I can handle this situation". There are many other short expressions which are not grammatically suspicious at all, for example "Let me!" and "I get this!"

Comment: @Betty: *I get this* is just as suspicious (and rare, in my experience) as *I got this*.  But (since it's Wimbledon fortnight) *Mine!* seems a good choice.

Comment: @TimLymington "Mine!" seems a really good choice. And it is very concise, only one syllable.

Comment: Fair enough, I had forgotten about "Mine" (and its opposite, "Yours").  It's been a while since I've roamed the outfield in an organized baseball game..

Answer (score 13):

"I got this" (or *slightly* more grammatically "I've got this") means **"I've taken this on,"** "I know what to do about this and I'll do it," "No-one else needs to do anything."

A [rugby] footballer or cricketer (or baseball player perhaps) might call "I got this" when he's about to catch the ball falling from the sky, to indicate that he's **made the decision to deal with it [same tense]** and other players shouldn't interfere — which runs the risk of no-one catching it. It's now applied to other situations such as that in *How I met your Mother*.

Comment: I'm afraid "he's made the decision" is not past tense, but present perfect tense. "He's made" is short for "he has made". "I've got this" is also present perfect tense, where "I've" is short for "I have". The auxiliary verb is of vital importance to present perfect tense. One can't just drop it. There must be some reason.

Comment: How about colloquialism? (I've adjusted the answer)

Comment: I like your rugby example. :) And for colloquialism, I don't know, I think tense is a very solid part of English. People don't mess with tenses even in colloquial language.

Comment: @Betty: In American English, there is a difference between "got" and "gotten". "I have gotten" is the present perfect tense for "get". "I've got" is another way of saying "I have", and except for the grammatical form, there is nothing about the way it's used that corresponds to the perfect tense. So the tense of "I've got" is **already** messed up. It seems to me that dropping the "ve" and just using "I got" doesn't mess the tense up any more than it already was.

Comment: the more I think about this verb 'get' the more complex it (ahem) gets.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see it as being Past Tense at all.

People say "**got**" all the time in casual spoken English, as in "**I got your back**," "**I got a lot riding on this one**," "**I'm giving it all that I got**" etc. Even the ubiquitous "**gtg**" online (got to go).

None of these is really in the Past.

The often unrecognizable expression is "Have got," which is also different from the Present Perfect (Have P.P.).

---

"Have got" is the same as "Have." The added "got" is just there for rhythm and doesn't give any special meaning. It's not the same as the P.P. "gotten" (American) and "got" (British).

So it is not precise to say that we are presuming a Past (done deal) Action when we are still in the Present.

Perhaps one could say we are presuming a Present condition when the task is still in the Future, yet to be accomplished.

But the OP has already mentioned that a meeting of will and act in the Present Tense is understandable.

I also found this from [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv323.shtml):

> 'have' / 'have got'   When we are talking about possession,
>   relationships, illnesses and characteristics of people or things we
>   can use either have or have got. The have got forms are more common in
>   an informal style.
>
> Have got has the same meaning as have and both are used as present
>   tenses.

Answer (score 3):

The use of "got" in any such usage where the context is present tense, the "got" intends to emphasize the surety/need for urgency.

> ***Surety*** as in "Don't worry, I got (confidence that he/she already has a plan to take care of the task, so consider it's already being attended) it"

*OR*

> ***urgency*** as in "I got (its so urgent that consider me gone already) to go".

That's pretty much i could think, I hope that answers the question.