# "Have got" — verb form and tense

Tags: verbs, idioms, tenses, have-got

In the following sentence, what is the main verb and in what tense does it occur?

> I have got a car.

There are two possible explanations that I can think of:

- *get* as the main verb in the present perfect tense
- *have got* as a phrasal verb in the present simple tense

Comment: Related: [Difference between “I have got” and “I have gotten”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten), [Why past tense in 'I got this'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67590/why-past-tense-in-i-got-this), [When can 'have' be used without 'got'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/when-can-have-be-used-without-got)

Answer (score 12):

To answer the original question, it's **Present** tense, and the verb construction is **Perfect**. Together they're often called "Present Perfect", which is a tense in Latin. but only a construction in English.

Yes, *have got* is an idiom; but that explains nothing except its irregularity, of course. And it's a different idiom in UK English than it is in American English, where it contrasts with *have gotten.*  Like most idioms, where it came from is a long tortuous story.

*Get* means *come to be* **or** *come to have*, as in

- *He got tired.*  ~  *He became tired.*

**or**

- *He got his orders.*  ~  *He received his orders.*

(I've always been bemused that in German
the verb *bekommen* means *receive* but **not** *become*.)

In the case of *have*, especially, if one comments on the acquisition
of something, the implicature is that one still has it -- otherwise,
one would say something different. So the present perfect of *get*
naturally implicates the present of "*have*", leading to the equivalence
of *have got* and *have*.

The Present Perfect construction uses the auxiliary verb *have/has*,
plus the past participle of the matrix verb:

- *I have/He has gone.*

The past participle of *get* is *got* [or *gotten* in the US](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gotten.html); UK
mileage may vary. There is a principled distinction between the two,
since *get* -- as the [inchoative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63473/15299) form of both *be* and *have* -- is itself an auxiliary, and *got* has come to have its own
usages in American English, leaving the simple Past Participle slot
to be filled by *gotten*.

As [McCawley points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53188/15299), one of the functions of the Perfect
is to report past actions still relevant in the present; thus,

- *I've got a cold*

reports a past event (*catching the cold*) which is still relevant
(*having the cold*), and, since pragmatically what we're interested in is
the present state, *I've got a cold* is used more often to warn people to
duck when I sneeze than to comment on the events of the past week.

But wait – there's more.  Both *be* and *have* are already auxiliary verbs, and
are used in many constructions, like Passive or Perfect.  Since *get*
can implicate *be* and *have* in some cases, it's been generalized to
substitute in others, where their use is grammatical instead of
meaningful, like the so-called ***Get*-Passive**

- *He got arrested.* ~  *He was arrested.*  =  *s.b. arrested him*.

or in the periphrastic modal *have to* meaning *must*

- *He's got to go. ~  He has to go.*  =  *He must go.*

(frequently spelled *gotta*, because the /v/ or /z/ in /ðevgaɾə/ /hizgaɾə/ is usually inaudible)

or simply, **wherever** one might use *have*

- *I got a new DVD.*  ~  *I have a new DVD.*

Quite frequently children generalize this equivalence to produce
sentences like

- *He gots a new ball.*

in effect, inventing a new verb because the old one has worn out.

Got all that?

Comment: Sorry it's so long, but this is a **really** complex topic. I scavenged this from an old a.u.e post on this perennial topic; there's plenty more there, but I forbear.

Answer (score 6):

The verb is "have got." It is neither a phrasal verb nor a verb in present perfect tense.

"Have got" is equivalent to "have."

Ex.

> I have a car. = I have got a car.
>
> Do you have a car? = Have you got a car?
>
> I don't have a car. = I haven't got a car.

Comment: As opposed to “I’ve gone and gotten a car from Hertz for today.”

Comment: Yes, exactly @tchrist

Answer (score 2):

It's a present perfect constuction consisting of the present tense of the auxiliary verb *have* and the past participle of the main verb *get*. It is, I understand, found less in American English than in British English.

Comment: Barrie, it’s not exactly that *got* is especially less used in AE. We would use it here just as you would. (I’m discounting grammar-school teachers who would delete it as an ugly or superfluous word.) It’s just that we use the *gotten* form when we mean something we’ve received rather than something we simply possess.  “I’ve got mail” means that you possess it, while “I’ve gotten mail’ means that you’ve received it.  We may also use it as a more general past participle, as in “That’s not something I’ve ever gotten around to doing”, in which for us the *got* version doesn’t sound quite right.

Comment: Also, “I’ve got mail” is for us something that is talking about present conditions, while “I’ve gotten mail” is referring to a past event.  So there is a tense-like implication here as well.

Comment: I notice @tchrist contracted "have" in all of his examples, which I would do as well. Is that preference particular to American English?

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, that must have been partly, at least, what I was thinking of. BrEng doesn't make that distinction, at least not in that way.

Comment: @Cameron: I don't think AmEng and BrEng are any different in that respect.

Comment: @tchrist: In general I tend to perceive *gotten* as something of an Americanism, but I do also use it myself in certain contexts. Not quite with the distinction you make though - to me, if I've *gotten* something, I haven't just *received it* - I've *performed deliberate and/or specific actions **in order to "get" it***. Thus I could feasibly refer to *"my gotten mail"* if I'd specifically invoked my email client to fetch it, but ***not*** if it had just turned up in the background because the client was running anyway, and I'd just brought the client window to the foreground on my screen.

Comment: No one want to dispute my analysis of the construction as the present perfect form of 'get'?

Comment: I would disagree about its frequency; *have got* meaning *have* is very common in American English. It just is not as acceptable in formal language. In fact, it is so common that we have a special past participle *(got)* for this meaning. For all other uses, the past participle is *gotten*.

Comment: It certainly deconstructs as a present perfect if you look at "have got" in isolation, but it feels like a regular old present to me (since you're asking for disputes). I'm not really sure why the form acts the way it does, though, so I don't have the wherewithal to debate the point. @CoolElf's answer sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: I believe Americans indeed treat *have got* as a present tense verb, and not a past participle. In the U.K., the standard answer to "have you got any bananas?" would be "yes, we have," while in the U.S., I suspect most people would answer "yes, we do." (As opposed to, say, "have you gotten today's mail yet", for which the standard answer would  be "yes, I have.")

Comment: Yes. See, for example, [this discussion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the previous example, when the mother exclaimed (of the keys) "I have got them", the emphasis is clearly on the subject pronoun "I" and the fact that there is no present need for father and son to continue searching for the keys. The emphatic interjection is strengthened by using I've got 'em, rather than  "I have them"

Answer (score -1):

I am open to being corrected but surely there is a difference between *have* and *have got*, albeit slight.

I read everywhere the example:

> I have a car.

vs

> I have got a car.

And that they both equally imply possession.

I agree that they do but with different connotations. One is in the present simple and one is in the present perfect simple — and so the meaning for me is slightly different.  Let me use a better example in a clearer context.

A father and his son want to go for a drive. The father looks for his keys and can’t find them so they both start an hour long search for the keys. Suddenly the father’s son spies them under a chair, grabs them and jumps to his feet with the keys in his hand and shouts: “I have them!”

Now imagine the same scenario but where the keys are not under the chair. After the hour long search the keys are still nowhere to be found. At this point the mother enters the room and asks what all the fuss is. They explain to her that they are looking for the keys and she replies: “I have got them!”

She reaches into her pocket and pulls them out, proving that she had them all along.

Using this example we see “I have them” means the possession of the keys comes into being in the present moment, whereas “I have got them” means possession came into being at some time in the past with the result being that they are in her possession at this moment.

So if we return to the previous example of the car:

“I have a car” means I have in my possession the use of a car; in other words, I can give you a lift somewhere right now.

However, “I have got a car” means that at some time in the past I came into possession of a car that is still my property.

This is my understanding of the difference but please, please correct me if I am wrong.

I do understand that in spoken English we mix the terms and meanings but surely by definition this is the difference?

Comment: I think you're being more logical than those who use the idiom are! What you say makes sense, but doesn't match actual usage. "I have got a large family, I'm the youngest of eight" would be said by someone who always had a large family. There's also the fact that it's combining a word that means a change of state with an aspect that means a continual state, which reduces the emphasis on change that *get* normally has.

Answer (score -2):

"Have got" can never be a grammatically correct present per construction because the main verb has to be in the 3rf form (past participle).
Nevertheless, sometimes,  as a colloquialism, it is used as the present perfect, as in:

"I've just got called to work. They have an emergency, and 
   they need me to come right away."

The only way to use it as a grammatically sound present perfect construction is by putting the main verb into the 3rd form:

"I've just gotten home, so i simply want to rest."

Although both the former and the latter sound somewhat awkward.

Comment: P. S.: People would rather say "I just got called" and "I've just come home." At least in American English.