# The Drop - meaning of "get to"

Tags: grammar, questions

What does "get to" mean in the following excerpt taken from the book "The Drop" by Michael Connelly? The "Get to" is at the end of the excerpt. I have written it in bold. Thank you very much for the help.

> “Harry,” the lieutenant said. “Hang back a second.”
>   Bosch looked at Chu and raised his eyebrows. He didn’t know what this was about. The lieutenant came around from behind her desk and closed the door after Chu and Marcia had left. She stayed standing and businesslike.
>   “I just wanted you to know that your application for an extension on your DROP came through. They gave you four years retroactive.”
>   Bosch looked at her, doing the math. He nodded. He had asked for the maximum — five years non-retroactive — but he’d take what they gave. It wouldn’t keep him much past high school but it was better than nothing.
>   “Well, I’m glad,” Duvall said. “It gives you thirty-nine more months with us.”
>   Her tone indicated that she had read disappointment in his face.
>   “No,” he said quickly. “I’m glad. I was just thinking about where that would put me with my daughter. It’s good. I’m happy.”
>    “Good then.”
>   That was her way of saying the meeting was over. Bosch thanked her and left the office. As he stepped back into the squad room he looked across the vast expanse of desks and dividers and file cabinets. He knew it was home and that he would **get to** stay — for now.

Comment: in this context you could directly replace 'get to' with be allowed to

Answer (score 4):

"He gets to stay" is the same as "He *can* stay" or "He *is able* to stay".

You can use "get to" when, for whatever reason, you are able to do something.

For example, the following is valid:

> If you join our club you get to go on some interesting trips.

Answer (score 1):

*Get* has numerous meanings and shades of meaning in English.  In this context *[get](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get)* means to be able to do something

> 1 b (intransitive): to reach or enter into a certain condition *got to sleep after midnight*

Answer (score 1):

*Get* does indeed have a lot of meanings; most of them, as here, are idiomatic.

This particular *get* idiom consists of the verb *get*, in all its inflected and uninflected forms, as required by the construction, plus an immediately following *to*-infinitive clause.
I.e,

- *I get to see him every day*. ~ *She got to go last year; this year it's my turn.*

In semantics, it's a paraphrase for the modal auxiliary verb *may*, in its deontic sense of 'be allowed', though *get to* doesn't have the implication of overt authority that *be allowed to* does.

*Be able to* -- another modal paraphrase, for *can* -- in a particular sense referring to whims of fate, is often closer in sense, though that particular sense of *be able to* goes far beyond any literal sense of personal capability.

- *I'm allowed to see him every day*. ~ *She was allowed to go last year; this year it's my turn.*
- *I'm able to see him every day*. ~ *She was able to go last year; this year it's my turn.*

This idiomatic modal paraphrase
 - *get* + *to* `Infinitive` (paraphrasing *may*, in its deontic 'be allowed/able to' sense)
is in parallel with the **other** `Auxiliary` + *to* `Infinitive` modal paraphrases:
 - *have to* (paraphrasing *must*, usually only in its deontic 'be obliged to' sense), and
 - *be to* (paraphrasing *will*, usually only in its epistemic 'future; scheduled' sense).

- *I have to see him every day*. ~ *She had to go last year; this year it's my turn.*
- *I am to see him every day*. ~ *She was to go last year; this year it's my turn.*

*Get to* is not to be confused, by the way, with *gotta*, [from *have/has got to*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76141/15299), yet another modal paraphrase (equivalent to *have to*). They're easy to confuse in print, but in English, as usual, pronunciation distinguishes:
 - *We **got to** go*, meaning *we were able/allowed to go*, is pronounced /wiɡattəɡo/ (double /tt/)
 - *We('ve) **got to** go*, meaning *we must go*, is pronounced /wi(v)ɡaɾəɡo/ (/v/ is usually deleted)