# What is difference between GOT TO and HAVE TO

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I was searching today on this topic. i found some posts on web according to them

```
   1)  I got to go now.
   2)  I have to go now.
```

these two sentences are same but i wanna confirm that are they same ???

Comment: They mean the same.

Comment: FYI: *I got to go* is traditionally considered incorrect or informal. It is a shortened form of *I have got to go* (which means pretty much the same thing as *I have to go*, *I must go*, and *I need to go*).

Comment: @Drew Then why Americans use gotta go ???

Comment: What do you mean *why*? People often speak informally and in ways traditionally considered by some to be improper or incorrect. (*Gotta go* is of course short for *got to go*.) Why do people speak like this? Because it's easier, for one thing - igoddago is a quick or lazy way of saying *I have got to go*. And because it works: those who speak the same language, especially in the same place and context, understand what is being said.

Comment: [There are some reasons](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76141/15299), but they're complicated and involve several words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first sentence listed,

> "I got to go now."

Is a generally acceptable slang variant of the second sentence listed,

> "I have to go now."

They both mean the same thing, which is,

> "I need to go now."

*have to* and *need to* are more correct, but *got to* is common enough that no one will misunderstand you, and only the most pedantic among us will correct it.

Comment: The first sentence is *I've got to go now* missing the sound of the *'ve*.